# Please make x and y and z

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

This puzzle continues "[Please make 1 and 2 and 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30139/please-make-1-and-2-and-4/30140#30140)".

---

A mathematical expression is feasible, if it obeys the following rules:

- Any real number may be used
- One may use brackets "(" and ")" to structure the expression, and to make it well-defined
- The allowed mathematical operations are addition ($+$), subtraction ($-$), multiplication ($*$).
- Furthermore there is the special operation plus-minus ($\pm$).

Every feasible expression encodes the following set of numbers: every occurrence of $\pm$ in the expression is replaced once by $+$ and once by $-$, in all possible combinations.

> **Question:** Is it true that for any choice of three real numbers $x,y,z$, there does exist a feasible expression that encodes the set $\{x,y,z\}$?

Comment: [Supercat’s answer to the previous question](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/30149/11907) already proves the for every finite set of real numbers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We encode this with:

> $x + (\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2})*(y-x + (\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2})*(z-y))$

Explanation:

> Each $(\frac12\pm\frac12)$ is either 0 or 1. If the first is 0, we have x. If it is 1, we have x + y - x = y if the second is 0, or x + y - x + z - y = z if the second is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Start from $x$ and add $0$ or $1$ times either $y-x$ or $z-x$ so:

$$x+(\dfrac12\pm\dfrac12)\times(\dfrac{(z+y-2x)}{2}\pm\dfrac{z-y}{2})$$